# Number of function arguments equal to template integer

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have a class with an integer template argument. How would I go about adding a function that takes `N` arguments of a given type? If at all possible, I would like to avoid `enable_if` and the likes.

What I currently do is:

```
template<unsigned int N>
class Foo
{
    template <typename To, typename>
    using to = To;
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void Bar(to<char, Args>... args) // Some arguments of type char
    { /* do stuff */ }
};
```

This allows for calling Bar:

```
Foo<3> myfoo;
myfoo.Bar<int, int, int>('a', 'b', 'c');
```

However, I see two downsides. First, the number of arguments is not necessarily limited to `N`, except by maybe code inside `Bar`.

Second, the user is required to add template parameters to the function. Their values are not actually used, only the number of arguments. This seems unnecessary as we already have this, namely `N`.

Optimal use of the function would look like this:

```
Foo<3> myfoo;
myfoo.Bar('a', 'b', 'c'); // valid
```

The following calls generate compile errors. `function does not take this many arguments`, or some similar standard compile error  which you would get as if you would define `void(char, char, char)` by hand.

```
myfoo.Bar('a', 'b');
myfoo.Bar('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'); // error
myfoo.Bar('a', 'b', "flob"); // error
// ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using c++14 you could do it like this:

```
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
class Foo;

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
class Foo<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>{
    void Bar(decltype(Is, char{})... args) // Some arguments of type char
    { /* do stuff */ }
};
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NwJdo1FY8y7ECscH)

For c++11 you would need to implement `integer_sequence` to make it work... it could be done like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7MWccn4F45ORmN5l)

Comment: I was just about to post this... Dammit :D

Comment: Could you maybe explain what 'class =' does in the first template?

Comment: This is to as sign default value for the second template parameter. Using this you won't have t invoke Foo with two parameters.

Comment: What is more the value creates a sequence of indices from 0 to N-1 packed  in index_sequence "class"

Comment: Took me a while, but I now get what you do. Pretty smart.