# Is templated alias conducting inner and outer parameter packs non-deduced context?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, template-aliases

The problem came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793191/number-of-function-arguments-equal-to-template-integer/40793363) - I wanted to create an approach solving a little bit more general problem. Consider an example:

```
#include <utility>

template<class T, std::size_t>
using deduced = T;

template<std::size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct Foo;

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct Foo<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>{
    template <class... Args>
    void Bar(deduced<Args, Is>...)
    {  }
};

int main() {
   Foo<3> myfoo;
   myfoo.Bar(true, 2.0f, 3); // OK
   //myfoo.Bar(1, 2, 3, 4); // error
}
```

clang has no problem with compiling the code, gcc on the other hand shows following errors:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:18:27: error: no matching function for call to 'Foo<3ul>::Bar(bool, float, int)'
    myfoo.Bar(true, 2.0f, 3); // valid
                           ^
prog.cc:12:10: note: candidate: template<class ... Args> void Foo<N, std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, Is ...> >::Bar(deduced<Args, Is>...) [with Args = {Args ...}; long unsigned int N = 3ul; long unsigned int ...Is = {0ul, 1ul, 2ul}]
     void Bar(deduced<Args, Is>...)
          ^~~
prog.cc:12:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:18: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4x0m8p2jhNqGW1ZH)

What confuses me gcc does not have a problem with deduction when using the same alias but outer parameter pack isn't involved, e.g.:

```
void Bar(deduced<Args, 0>...)
```

So the question is - is it legal to combine parameter packs from outer and inner class with alias of this form to make compiler deduce one of the template parameters or is it gcc bug?

**Edit (based on bogdan's comment)**:

The code causes trouble also to MSVC (2017 RC), but works in this form with EDG compiler, icc (in version 16 and 17) also seem to deal well with a code. It is also worth noting that similar code with class instead of alias (also considered as deduced context in some places [example by bogdan](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/k9gVIb6k9GXSAAOR)) causes even more trouble to compilers - only clang seems to deal well with this version(?)

Comment: _confused by earlier errors, bailing out_ ... Somehow fantastic. :-) ... Anyway, this doesn't answer your question, but isn't enough a `static_assert` within the function to force the number of arguments? Much easier to read the errors too.

Comment: Your code causes an ICE with the latest version of MSVC (2017 RC), so you're definitely onto something here :-). EDG, however, compiles it as you intended.

Comment: @skypjack well in theory (when working) the code should be more sfinae friendly ([example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8TFHmiBPqUF4PqLP))

Comment: @bogdan my luck... why do I always have to break something :)

Comment: @W.F. sfinae is nothing more than a tool at our disposal, not the way to go for each problem. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack I'm not saying it is. I was just curious if the construct is possible and you asked when it would be useful so I gave you an example :)

Comment: A standard `enable_if` at the usual places will do the trick too. Interesting question though.

Comment: @W.F. The corresponding construct [using a class template](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/k9gVIb6k9GXSAAOR) yields interesting results as well: MSVC and Clang accept it, GCC "bails out" the same way, and EDG fails deduction. I expected this one to work everywhere; there's even [an example in the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#6) (OK, not involving deduction, but still).

Comment: @bogdan it just proves that EDG works differently with templated type aliases than with templated structs :)

Comment: @T.C. ok I got your point :)

Comment: The class template version works in MSVC as well, as I said above, so it doesn't cause more trouble - just about as much :-). Anyway, I don't think the standard disallows your code; as far as I can tell, it's valid and what you have uncovered are compiler bugs. If you want to report them, please post the links to the bug reports here so we can track them.

Comment: I'll try my best but it's quite a few groups to be informed... I'll post an answer when done